# How To Exclude System Table When Querying Sys.Tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running this SQL :

```
SELECT S.name as Owner, T.name as TableName FROM  sys.tables AS T
JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
```

And the result is:

```
Owner   TableName
------------------------
dbo         Person
dbo         Customer
dbo         sysdiagrams
```

`sysdiagrams` is a `system table` but showed in result.

**Update:**
Thanks all for your answers and comments, I'm using **Nate Bolam** & **vmvadivel** answers:

```
SELECT S.name as Owner, T.name as TableName 
FROM  
  sys.tables AS T
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EP ON EP.major_id = T.[object_id]
WHERE 
  T.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND 
  (EP.class_desc IS NULL OR (EP.class_desc <>'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' AND 
  EP.[name] <> 'microsoft_database_tools_support'))
```

Comment: `IS_MS_SHIPPED` may be a better property to use, if you also want to exclude e.g. objects added to the database to support replication (whereas the selected answer is only useful for excluding, specifically, the objects added to support diagrams)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: unfortunately, that `sysdiagrams` table doesn't have `is_ms_shipped = 1` set - so it won't be affected when you try to exclude all system tables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSMS uses an extended property to mark the sysdiagrams table as a sort of pseudo system table.

Try this:

```
SELECT S.name as Owner, T.name as TableName FROM  sys.tables AS T
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EP ON EP.major_id = T.[object_id]
WHERE (EP.class_desc IS NULL 
OR (EP.class_desc <> 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
    AND EP.[name] <> 'microsoft_database_tools_support'))
```

Comment: The `T.[Type] = 'U'` seems a bit redundant, since `sys.tables` already selects only objects of type `o.type = 'U'` in its definition

Comment: Removed redundant T.[Type] = 'U'

Comment: This excludes any table that has had a description added to a column.  Better `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.extended_properties EP WHERE EP.major_id = T.[object_id] AND EP.name = 'microsoft_database_tools_support')` or perhaps you meant `OR EP.[name]...`

Comment: Also, you might want to SELECT DISTINCT if you want to use a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `IS_MS_SHIPPED` for this. Hope the below script is what you are looking for

```
SELECT 
    S.[name] AS Owner, 
    T.[name] AS TableName 
FROM  
    sys.tables AS T JOIN sys.schemas AS S 
    ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE 
    T.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    AND T.[name] <> 'sysdiagrams'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Sure Marc_s. Thanks for letting me know about "code samples" button.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does **not** exclude the `sysdiagrams` table since that table doesn't have the `is_ms_shipped` flag set .....

Comment: I have edited my answer to ignore sysdiagrams explicitly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try with below query, thanks

```
SELECT S.name as Owner, T.name as TableName FROM  sys.tables AS T
JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE T.name <> 'sysdiagrams'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I believe this will only exclude `sysdiagrams` table, but I want to know if theres generic way to exclude all system table.

Comment: Usually, in each created database there is only one system table named `sysdiagrams`, so we can go with above query, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I'll give a variation on [Nate Bolam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775073/1157324)

```
SELECT S.name as Owner, T.name as TableName 
FROM  sys.tables AS T
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.extended_properties EP WHERE EP.major_id = T.[object_id] AND EP.name = 'microsoft_database_tools_support')
```